# Not able to open PDB database- Oracle standard edition

Tags: oracle, standards, oracle12c, pdb

I am using Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit on which I am facing a problem while opening PDB database.

**Error:**

```
SQL> select CON_ID,DBID,NAME,OPEN_MODE from v$pdbs;

CON_ID        DBID               NAME                   OPEN_MOD

----------   -------------     -------------------    -----------------

2             11247382            PDB$SEED                   READ ONLY

3             3988395454          PDB_ORCL12C                MOUNTED

SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL

SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_orcl12c OPEN READ WRITE FORCE;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb_orcl12c OPEN READ WRITE FORCE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
```

I am using below-mentioned steps for oracle database creation which is working fine on Oracle enterprise edition.

http://dbarahul.blogspot.in/2017/02/manual-cdb-pdb-database-creation-steps.html

Please help me to resolve this issue on Oracle standard edition.

Comment: Check `PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS` for any messages

Comment: I am getting "Database option DV mismatch: PDB installed version NULL. CDB installed version 12.1.0.2.0." message while checking PDB_PLUG_IN_VIOLATIONS view.

Answer (score 1):

According to the My Oracle Support, the error has occurred due to `Bug 21061354`.

Solution is to apply `patch 21061354`.

**Reference:** Alter Pluggable Database Open Returns ORA-01405 (Doc ID 2193378.1)

Comment: I tried to apply Patch 21061354 but it is the conflict with Other patches due to that I have to stop it. Summary of Conflict Analysis:

Summary of Conflict Analysis:
There are no patches that can be applied now.
Following patches have conflicts. Please contact Oracle Support and get the merged patch of the patches:
21061354, 21948354
Whole composite patch Conflicts/Supersets are:
Patch: 21061354
Conflict with Composite Patch 21948354